# Manually trigger a scroll event of DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two independent web elements, if I scroll the content of one element, I also want the 2nd element scroll at same time.  Here is an example: https://stackedit.io

I did the following code, but it is not working:

```
element.find('.fullscreen-mk-content-textarea').on('scroll', function(e){
    // first element will trigger this event, then manully trigger the 
    // the scroll of the 2nd element. It's my plan. 
    console.log(e); // works
    element.find('.right-side').trigger('scroll'); // doesn't work...
});
```

What shall I do?

Comment: Romeo's answer actually works, just don't forget that ID selector uses hash (#) instead of full stop (.) Hope this helped some beginner like me, who tries to find out how to trigger event on scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfco7xcz/).

```
$('.e1').scroll(function(e){
    $('.e2').scrollTop(parseInt($('.e1').scrollTop()));
});
```

Comment: Be wary using `parseInt(...)` here, because there could be floating point values when the user zoomed his/her browser in/out.

Answer (score 18):

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
var el = document.querySelector(".right-side");

el.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
```

Comment: Is there a jQuery code to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: If `.trigger('scroll')` is not working, then `$(document).get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));`

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the `scrollTop` value of the other to match.  That will cause it to scroll a desired amount.  That's how you scroll something.  It won't cause it to scroll by trying to trigger a scroll event.  A scroll event is an indicator of some scroll motion, not something that causes scroll motion.

If using jQuery, you can use `.scrollTop()` to retrieve the current value of the scroll or `.scrollTop(val)` to set the amount of scroll.